# Accessing an application running in VirtualBox through Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

Hi in my Windows machine I have installed Virtual Box on which I am running Linux-Ubuntu, and in the Linux I have a web application running in tomcat(localhost:8080). I want to access this application from my native Windows machine. Is it possible? If yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, explain what, in this question, relates to programming.

Comment: It will help my programming to be used practically.

Comment: You don't mention any programming in the question, and the answer isn't likely to involve programming either.

Answer (score 1):

The same way as any other web application would be, via its address (name or ip).  The fact its in a VM makes no difference to how you access.

So your first thing is to make sure your VM is properly connected to the rest of your network.

So you'll need to be checking/answering things like:
Can you see your router/modem from your VM?
Can you ping the host machine? Can the host ping the VM?

Most VM hosts automatically install the required networking stuff on the host (Windows probably bought up a driver install confirmation dialog when you first installed VirtualBox) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

May be ssh can help? You can create connection and have native bash commandline for example.
Putty is the most simple tool for it, imho
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html